# Typesetting problem

Tags: typography

I am currently writing an edited book chapter by using my institution template. The following is what I am currently working on.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage{bookchapters}
     \usepackage{cite}          
     \begin{document}
         \frontmatter
         \mainmatter
             \input{MNSAR.tex}   
         \backmatter
             \cleardoublepage %index odd numbered page
             \printindex %
\end{document}
```

where `\MNSAR.tex` contains normal chapters and sections. Meanwhile, the bookchapters package is as follows.

```
% For layout
  \setlength{\headheight}{5.5pc}         
  \setlength{\footskip}{1cm}            
  \setlength{\hoffset}{1cm}               
  \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{.75in}      
  \setlength{\evensidemargin}{.75in}    
  \setlength{\voffset}{-.3in}           
  \setlength{\topmargin}{-.15in}         
  \setlength{\headsep}{.55cm}            
  \setlength{\paperwidth}{6in}         
  \setlength{\paperheight}{9in}          
  \setlength{\textwidth}{4.5in}         
  \setlength{\textheight}{7in}           
  \setlength{\marginparwidth}{-.3cm}
%--------------------------------------------------------------     
% To get rid of default running head
  \pagestyle{myheadings}
%---------------------------------------------------------
% For no page number for first page of a chapter 
  \makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\ps@plain}{                         
    \renewcommand{\@oddhead}{} 
    \renewcommand{\@evenhead}{}          
    \renewcommand{\@evenfoot}{}                
    \renewcommand{\@oddfoot}{}  }               
  \makeatother
%---------------------------------------------------------
% For section font
  \usepackage{sectsty} 
    \sectionfont{\normalsize\uppercase}
    \subsectionfont{\normalsize}
    \subsubsectionfont{\itshape\normalsize}
%---------------------------------------------------------
% For no hyphentaion and right justified
   \hyphenpenalty=10000 \sloppy  
   \raggedbottom 
%---------------------------------------------------------
% For caption font size to be 11pt
  \makeatletter
   \long\def\@makecaption#1#2{\vskip 10\p@   
    \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{{\bf\small #1\,\,\,} \small #2} 
       \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize       
           {\bf\small #1\,\,\,} \small  #2\par   
       \else                                   
           \hbox to\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}  
       \fi}                                             
   \makeatother                               
%-------------------------------------------------------------
% To change 1. to (i) etc. in enumerate environment
  \renewcommand{\theenumi}{\textup{(\roman{enumi})}}
  \renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\theenumi}
%--------------------------------------------------------------    
% Coding for BookChapterHeader
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
 \vspace*{-27\p@} 
  {\parindent \z@ 
      \centering  
    \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
      \huge 
         \bfseries 
          \@chapapp\space \thechapter 
       \par\nobreak
           \vskip .25\baselineskip 
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
           \LARGE      
              \bfseries
 #1\par\nobreak 
\vskip 165\p@ 
  }}
\def\@schapter#1{\if@twocolumn
                   \@topnewpage[\@makeschapterhead{#1}]%
                 \else
                   \@makeschapterhead{#1}%
                   \@afterheading
                 \fi}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  {\parindent \z@
    \centering 
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \LARGE 
       \bfseries
 #1\par\nobreak  \vskip .25\baselineskip
    \vskip 217\p@        
  }}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
%--------------------------------------------------------------   
  \usepackage{graphicx}   %for .eps file
%-------------------------------------------------------------
  \usepackage{latexsym,amsmath,amssymb} % math symbols
  \usepackage{makeidx}\makeindex  %for index 
%--------------------------------------------------------------
% BookChaptersTheoremEnvironment
  \usepackage{theorem}
  \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
  \newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[chapter]
  \newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[chapter]
  \newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[chapter]
   {\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
   \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[chapter]
   \newtheorem{example}{Example}[chapter]}
  \newenvironment{proof}{\begin{paragraph}
          {Proof}}{\end{paragraph}}
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib} % list of ref. end of chapter
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\renewcommand{\bibname}{REFERENCES}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{times}        %text times roman
%----------------------------------------------------
 \usepackage[noframe]{crop} 
%----------------------------------------------------
```

However, when I try to typeset the above coding, I get the results as in the following figure.

[image]

I am aware that it is related to what type of output did I set. I am using Texstudio as my editor and it has an internal PDF viewer. Also, if I typeset them in PCTex, as DVI output, the results are shown properly. How can I typeset them in Texstudio and let the results be as PDF not DVI? I don't want to use PCTex since they do not update their software since years ago.

Added:
Dear @Simon Dispa, here I attached two figures as your reference for my request.
The first figure is the output by using your coding and the second figure is the output that I would like to achieve. Thank you.

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: I believe that the problem is in setting `\hoffset` and `\voffset` to nonzero values.

Comment: (1) Run the two files I posted: `MAIN.tex` with `bookchapters.sty` (not `bookchapters.tex`) in the same (but new) directory. If you get errors:

(2) Add `\listfiles` before `\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}`

(3) Check at the end of the log file. You should find  `crop.sty    2017/11/19 1.10 crop marks (mf)`. If not, update your system. Before you were using  `\usepackage[noframe]{crop}` which is not a valid option for crop! Not even in a old 2003 version.

Comment: Please the updated answer

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, you might want to use a clone of Times with math support. This could be `\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}` in PDFLaTeX, and `\usepackage{unicode-math}` `\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}` `\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}` in LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you wanted to print a 6x9in book using a letter paper size
I added the package `geometry` with this setup (and with the option `showframe`) and also modified the settings of the package `crop`.

[image: a]

This is the code of `File-Name.tex`

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{bookchapters}
\usepackage{cite}  

\usepackage{kantlipsum}    % added <<< 
   
\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \mainmatter
\chapter[Numerical Solution]{Numerical Solution of the Acoustic Wave Equation}

\section{INTRODUCTION}
1. \kant[1-9]

    \backmatter
    \cleardoublepage %index odd numbered page
%   \printindex %
\end{document}
```

And this is the modified `bookchapters.sty`  (lines maked as `% changed` or `% added`)

```
%%----------------------------------------------------bookchapters starts
%% For layout
\usepackage[papersize={6in,9in},left=0.75in,top=0.2in,margin=0.75in, includehead,includefoot,showframe]{geometry} % added <<<

\setlength{\headheight}{1cm}      % changed   
\setlength{\footskip}{1cm}   % changed
\setlength{\textwidth}{4.5in}         
\setlength{\textheight}{7in}           
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0cm} % changed
\setlength{\marginparsep}{0cm}% changed

\usepackage[cam,letter,center]{crop} % changed
%%--------------------------------------------------------------     
% To get rid of default running head
\pagestyle{myheadings}
%---------------------------------------------------------
% For no page number for first page of a chapter 
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\ps@plain}{                         
    \renewcommand{\@oddhead}{} 
    \renewcommand{\@evenhead}{}          
    \renewcommand{\@evenfoot}{}                
    \renewcommand{\@oddfoot}{}  }               
\makeatother
%---------------------------------------------------------
% For section font
\usepackage{sectsty} 
\sectionfont{\normalsize\uppercase}
\subsectionfont{\normalsize}
\subsubsectionfont{\itshape\normalsize}
%---------------------------------------------------------
% For no hyphentaion and right justified
\hyphenpenalty=10000 \sloppy  
\raggedbottom 
%---------------------------------------------------------
% For caption font size to be 11pt
\makeatletter
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{\vskip 10\p@   
    \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{{\bf\small #1\,\,\,} \small #2} 
    \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize       
    {\bf\small #1\,\,\,} \small  #2\par   
    \else                                   
    \hbox to\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}  
    \fi}                                             
\makeatother                               
%-------------------------------------------------------------
% To change 1. to (i) etc. in enumerate environment
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\textup{(\roman{enumi})}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\theenumi}
%--------------------------------------------------------------    
% Coding for BookChapterHeader
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{-27\p@} 
    {\parindent \z@ 
        \centering  
        \normalfont
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \if@mainmatter
        \huge 
        \bfseries 
        \@chapapp\space \thechapter 
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip .25\baselineskip 
        \fi
        \fi
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \LARGE      
        \bfseries
        #1\par\nobreak 
        \vskip 165\p@ 
}}
\def\@schapter#1{\if@twocolumn
    \@topnewpage[\@makeschapterhead{#1}]%
    \else
    \@makeschapterhead{#1}%
    \@afterheading
    \fi}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
    {\parindent \z@
        \centering 
        \normalfont
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \LARGE 
        \bfseries
        #1\par\nobreak  \vskip .25\baselineskip
        \vskip 217\p@        
}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
%--------------------------------------------------------------   
\usepackage{graphicx}   %for .eps file
%-------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{latexsym,amsmath,amssymb} % math symbols
\usepackage{makeidx}\makeindex  %for index 
%--------------------------------------------------------------
% BookChaptersTheoremEnvironment
\usepackage{theorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[chapter]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[chapter]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[chapter]
{\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
    \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[chapter]
    \newtheorem{example}{Example}[chapter]}
\newenvironment{proof}{\begin{paragraph}
        {Proof}}{\end{paragraph}}
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib} % list of ref. end of chapter
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\renewcommand{\bibname}{REFERENCES}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{times}        %text times roman
%%----------------------------------------------------bookchapters ends
```

If you want to have the section titles in bold face, comment the section `%Coding for BookChapterHeader`  and `\usepackage{times}` in `bookchapters.sty`, then add  `\chapterfont{\centering \bfseries}` at the end.

[image: b]

**UPDATE** `crop` output closer to the institution template
[image: c]

Add the file `crop.cfg` to the working directory.

```
%% file crop.cfg (to be placed in the working directory)

\renewcommand*\CROP@@ulc{%
    \begin{picture}(0,0)
        \unitlength\p@\thinlines
        \put(-35,0){\line(1,0){30}}
        \put(0,35){\line(0,-1){30}}
    \end{picture}%
}
\renewcommand*\CROP@@urc{%
    \begin{picture}(0,0)
        \unitlength\p@\thinlines
        \put(35,0){\line(-1,0){30}}
        \put(0,35){\line(0,-1){30}}
    \end{picture}%
}
\renewcommand*\CROP@@llc{%
    \begin{picture}(0,0)
        \unitlength\p@\thinlines
        \put(-35,0){\line(1,0){30}}
        \put(80,-20){\itshape Paper width:\,\the\paperwidth}  % adjust h-v position
        \put(240,-20){\itshape Paper height:\,\the\paperheight} % adjust h-v position
        \put(0,-35){\line(0,1){30}}
    \end{picture}%
}
\renewcommand*\CROP@@lrc{%
    \begin{picture}(0,0)
        \unitlength\p@\thinlines
        \put(35,0){\line(-1,0){30}}
        \put(0,-35){\line(0,1){30}}
    \end{picture}%
}

\renewcommand*\CROP@@info{{%
        \global\advance\CROP@index\@ne
        \def\x{\discretionary{}{}{\hbox{\kern.5em---\kern.5em}}}%
        \advance\paperwidth-20\p@
        \dimen@4pt
        \ifx\CROP@pagecolor\@empty
        \else
        \advance\dimen@\CROP@overlap
        \fi
        \hb@xt@\z@{%
            \hss
            \vbox to\z@{%
                \centering
                \hsize\paperwidth
                \vss
                \itshape
                \normalsize
                \expandafter\csname\CROP@font\endcsname{%
                    Job:\kern.4em \jobname\kern10em
                    Sheet:\kern.3em\the\CROP@index\kern1em
                    Page:\kern.3em\thepage      
                    \strut
                }%          
                \vskip\dimen@       
            }%  
            \hss        
        }%
}}

\endinput
```

Comment: I am adding your changes and it seems that I have a problem with the `crop` package. It says that - Unknown option 'cam' for package 'crop'. It also the same for the 'letter' and 'center' for the crop package. What should I do? And what is the problem with the crop package?

Comment: @Syiham Razak (1) Run the two files I posted: `MAIN.tex` with `bookchapters.sty` (not `bookchapters.tex`) in the same (but new) directory. If you get errors:

(2) Add `\listfiles` before `\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}`

(3) Check at the end of the log file. You should find  `crop.sty    2017/11/19 1.10 crop marks (mf)`. If not, update your system. Before you were using  `\usepackage[noframe]{crop}` which is not a valid option for crop! Not even in a old 2003 version.

Comment: Dear @Simon Dispa, thank you so much as it works perfectly. However, is it possible if I ask for your help one more time? I want that the output be the same as my institution template, where there is no circled plus symbol (I don't know what to call them) at the corner of the page. Also, I want the info for the top part shown as "Job: File Name 
   Sheet: No of Page    Page: No of Page" and the info for the bottom part shown as "Paper width: 433.62pt    Paper height: 650.43pt". I have added two figures in my original post for reference. I am looking forward to your help. Thank you.

Comment: @Syiham Razak I updated the answer. Glad that the former answer finally worked. Thank you for your feedback!!

Comment: Dear @Simon Dispa, the added .cfg file also does work properly. Thank you again for your help.